# Run python file on shared drive without installing python or python frameworks

Tags: python

I have placed a Pythonfile at a shared drive that I want any user to be able to start. I don't want the user to install python or any of the libraries needed (e.g pandas).

I want it to be easy for the user to start the program. How should I do that?

I have tried to create a bat-file (Z: is the shared drive location. All users will have it as their Z-drive):

```
@echo off
    Z:\python27\python.exe  Z:\main.py %*
    pause
```

I tried to install python at the shared drive (as specified) and placed all needed imports at the shared drive.

From my computer this is runnable. But from a users computer I get the error message:

```
ImportError: C extension: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be fou
nd. not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may n
eed to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first
```

I have Python 2.7, the Teradata module and Pandas installed. What can I do to make this runnable?

Comment: A computer cannot execute a python script if there's no python interpreter installed, so there's likely no way around that unless you convert the python script into a compiled binary executable (i.e. an `.exe` file).

Answer (score 0):

`PyPy` does that out of the box.

`CPython` has some sort of redistributable bundle which should suit your use-case.

Finally, there are these projects:

- http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/movpy/
- http://portablepython.com/

Comment: How should I set this up? It must work on a shared drive where the user doesn't download pandas, the teradata module or Python. How can this be done?